# br not working as per required

Tags: html, css

I want to create a div which contains some data. Which need to be shown as in the picture below:[image: div image]

I have used html for it as follows:

```
<div class="mydiv">
     <span>Major</span><br>
     <span>Minor</span>
     <span style="float: right; margin-right:5%" id="span_store">
         <img src="edit.png">
         <a onmousedown="javascript:myfun('name');" style="padding-left:10px"></img>
                <img src="active.png"></img>
         </a>
     </span>
 </div>
```

I want the 2 images coming on the extreme right side to appear in between (i.e. neither top nor a bottom). How can I do that.

I think `<BR>` is creating problem in this case. but i need to show Major and Minor in similar way as in image. Please provide any alternative to it.

Comment: That code you have posted works fine for me. Check that it is no inheriting some other CSS you might have created.

Comment: Also putting the style inline like that my make problems for you later when you need to change some thing.

Comment: thanks Will. I am also suspecting that my other css might be creating problem. i am working over it.

Comment: Open it in your browser's debugger and interactively toggle css rules on/off. You'll see what is interfering in next to no time!

Comment: You should be closing your tags off like so: `<br />` but really you shouldn't use that tag for line breaks anyway, it's much better semantically to force things onto different lines with propertys like `width` in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to:

```
<div class="mydiv">
   <span style="float: right; margin-right:5%" id="span_store">
     <img src="edit.png" style="display:block"/>
     <a onmousedown="javascript:myfun('name');" 
         style="padding-left:10px display:block">
            <img src="active.png"/>
     </a>
   </span>
   <span style="display:block">Major</span>
   <span style="display:block">Minor</span>

</div>
```

So things I've changed

1. removed `</img>` as it is not needed just close and end the tag in one place
2. Moved the "img" `span` above the others, so the float works
3. marked spans as `display:block` to fill whole line, this is preferred to `br` tags. As it is more flexible and helps with issues around floating, such as this
4. you had a `img` enclosing a `a` tag, this won't work:

fiddle of code:

http://jsfiddle.net/RcKRb/2/

Comment: You have removed the br tag so it does not appear on the different lines any more.

Comment: Indeed. Star, you can use the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to well... validate your markup before anything when you find any errors in your html.

Comment: You should try and avoid `<br>` tags. Use `display:block` instead. The means your flow is not in your HTML

Comment: Also like @Will says use a css file!